# SQL Server 2008: Group Databases

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

In SQL Server Management Studio is there a property to set so you can group databases? Or can make a folder in SSMS to "move" those databases to?

Comment: Since 2005, we use schemas instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such feature currently in SSMS, as far as I know.

You can group servers in the Registered Servers window, but I don't think there's any way to group databases in the Object Explorer into "folders" or groups.

Might want to register that with Microsoft Connect as a feature request!

Comment: There was back in SQL 2000. There are things about Enterprise Manager that I still miss.